# Force break line after form to a table - html

Tags: html, image

I have two forms which are on the same block. I want to put an table after it but it doesnt get on a new line and sticks to the second form. [See picture](https://serving.photos.photobox.com/7505671230dddb9fdcdd1248043261ce918cbae9a6beb4a0e8afa6a69b406e7d3974e17f.jpg) , in the picture you can see the last element showing as Cry and Lite ... that is the table which is not getting line break. I have the following code:-

```
<div style="display: flex;">
<form name="myform" method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:left;">
    <div id="log_err"> <strong>
            <?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?>
            <?php if(isset($tm)) { echo $tm; } ?>
            <?php if(isset($tah)) { echo $tah; } ?>
            <?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> </div>
    <p><label style="float: left;">Price:</label><input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="uprice"
            id="box1" oninput="calculate()"><label style="float: right;">:
            <?php echo $market; ?></label><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="uam" id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
        <br><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="utam" id="result"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total
            <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="myform" value="1">
            <br><span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="ordersell" onclick="myform.submit()">SELL</span></p>
    </td>

</form>
<form name="yourform" method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:right;">
    <div id="log_err"> <strong>
            <?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?>
            <?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> </div>
    <p><label style="float: left;">Price:</label><input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="username"
            id="box3" oninput="calculate()"><label style="float: right;">:
            <?php echo $market; ?></label><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box4" oninput="calculate()">
        <br><input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="resul"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total
            <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="yourform" value="1">
            <br>
            <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="orderbuy" onclick="yourform.submit()">BUY</span></p>
    </td>

</form>
<div class="abcd">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="data-table">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="btcaddresses">


                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Crypto</th>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="images/Mltc.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-right: 5px; ">Litecoin</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**
I found the error myself. Division with style="display: flex was ending after table causing the problem just removed a `</div>` at last and placed it after second `</form>`

Comment: your html is completely invalid

Comment: Hmmmm, I suppose you didn't read the question and just told me that html is invalid right? Where am I wrong in it?

Comment: Nope I read the question gave you a comment that you have invalid html, you can back with a sarcastic comment saying that's why it works, so I replied to your sarcasm with sarcasm of my own (which admittedly I shouldn't have done) but hey if you want to continue coding invalid html and ignoring it just because it "works" then go ahead (you are being penalised in a lot of other areas like seo and accessibility and other such things), but if you prefer not to fix the html - which would be the starting point to fixing your new line issue, then there's no help that can be given

Comment: @JeffB chill bro. See a few of the <tr> are closed incorrectly.

Comment: @Krishanu I am chilling out bro. I see, regret on my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is, I'm sorry to say this, horrendous. Tags are not closed properly, some tags are not even closed. Tables act funny in HTML that if you don't close them, non-table tags appear above the table. I fixed up your HTML, it should work better for you.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:left;">
        <div id="log_err"> <strong><?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?><?php if(isset($tm)) { echo $tm; } ?><?php if(isset($tah)) { echo $tah; } ?><?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> </div>  
        <p>
            <label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
            <input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="uprice" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
            <label style="float: right;">: <?php echo $market; ?></label>
            <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="uam" id="box2" oninput="calculate()"><br>
            <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="utam" id="result"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="myform" value="1">
                <br>
                <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="ordersell" onclick="myform.submit()">SELL</span>
            </td>
        </p>

    </form>
    <form name="yourform" method="post" action="usdbtc.php" style="float:right;">
        <div id="log_err">
            <strong><?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?><?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> 
        </div>  
        <p>
            <label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
            <input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="username" id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
            <label style="float: right;">: <?php echo $market; ?></label>
            <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box4" oninput="calculate()"><br>
            <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="resul"><br>
            <label style="padding: 10px;">Total <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="yourform" value="1">
                <br>
                <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="orderbuy" onclick="yourform.submit()">BUY</span>
            </td>
        </p>
    </form>
    <div class="abcd"></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="data-table">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="btcaddresses">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Crypto</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="images/Mltc.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-right: 5px; ">
                            Litecoin
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```